# How to set the number of photos in flickr

Tags: php, zend-framework, flickr

I am reading [this page about Zend_Service_Flickr](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.service.flickr.html). However it does not say how to set up the number of photos showing.

The following code returns 10 images.

```
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Service_Flickr');
$flickr = new Zend_Service_Flickr($this->flickrapikey);
$results = $flickr->userSearch($this->flickemail);
```

Could anyone tell me how to set it up please?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at the code source of `Zend_Service_Flickr::userSearch` *(see [here](http://framework.zend.com/svn/framework/standard/tags/release-1.9.6/library/Zend/Service/Flickr.php) for instance)*, you'll notice it starts with this piece of code :

```
/**
 * Finds photos by a user's username or email.
 *
 * Additional query options include:
 *
 *  # per_page:        how many results to return per query
 *  # page:            the starting page offset.  first result will be (page - 1) * per_page + 1
 *  # min_upload_date: Minimum upload date to search on.  Date should be a unix timestamp.
 *  # max_upload_date: Maximum upload date to search on.  Date should be a unix timestamp.
 *  # min_taken_date:  Minimum upload date to search on.  Date should be a MySQL datetime.
 *  # max_taken_date:  Maximum upload date to search on.  Date should be a MySQL datetime.
 *
 * @param  string $query   username or email
 * @param  array  $options Additional parameters to refine your query.
 * @return Zend_Service_Flickr_ResultSet
 * @throws Zend_Service_Exception
 */
public function userSearch($query, array $options = null)
{
    static $method = 'flickr.people.getPublicPhotos';
    static $defaultOptions = array('per_page' => 10,
                                   'page'     => 1,
                                   'extras'   => 'license, date_upload, date_taken, owner_name, icon_server');
    ...
    ...
```

This should be enough to help you understand how to specify how many photos you'd like to get : you probably just have to pass an array as second parameter, containing an entry with the key "`per_page`", and the value you want.

Somethong like this, I suppose *(not tried, though)* :

```
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Service_Flickr');
$flickr = new Zend_Service_Flickr($this->flickrapikey);
$results = $flickr->userSearch($this->flickemail, array(
    'per_page' => 20
  ));
```

When the documentation is not good enough, don't hesitate to take a look at the code ;-)